# mySQL time stamp error and insert completing but not showing

Tags: python, mysql

I am currently pulling records from one database and I am inserting them into another with an intermediate of a csv file. However I am encountering an error. The error is:

```
Warning: Out of range value for column 'time stamp' at row 1
```

cursor.execute(insert, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]))

Which is odd because my time stamp column is formatted as a time stamp column so i should not be getting this error (one possibility is that the time stamp is now a string but how would i got about fixing this?) This then causes my timestamp column to be 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I think the issue stems from my insert statement.

```
    inputinfo=csv.reader(open('Database.csv','rb'), delimiter=',')
    for row in inputinfo:
        insert=("""insert into table (id,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);""")
        cursor.execute(insert, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10]))
```

Comment: Could you show the definition of your table? And few examples of the actual content you tried to insert (i.e.: `print(row[0..9])`) ? BTW, could someone confirm that `insert into table (id,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) ...` is really a valid MySQL statement ?!?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column for time ?

Comment: the insert statement does work, the timestamp column is datetime. I can't show you the information (company sensitive) but i can tell you that columns 0-9 are all varchar, ive also edited please take a look at the changes. The table is a pre existing table i am inserting into.

Comment: I resolved the issue my columns were just off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 11 columns but you inserting only 10 values.